# I can receive UDP data but how do I send it simultaneously to ws websocket connected clients using c#?

Tags: c#, websocket, udpclient

I can accept UDP messages from connected devices on the local network.  I need to send that data to connected websocket clients.  When new data is received, it needs to be sent to the websocket clients for real-time updates.  I listen for the UDP data in a new thread.  When the data is received, I don't know how to pass that data to the websocket clients.  All clients will receive the same data.  There won't be more than 2 or 3 websocket clients connected at any given time.  UDP data is sent on the local network to a designated port.  The goal is for the UDP data to show up on web pages in real-time.

The UDP data needs to be received even if there are no websocket clients connected.  The UDP data is also put into a database as it's received.

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Receiver v1.0.0");
        ExternalVariables Ev = new ExternalVariables();
        Ev.Get();

        UdpReceiver r = new UdpReceiver();
        r.Port = Ev.ReceivingPort;
        Thread ControllerThread = new Thread(r.ReceiveMessages);
        ControllerThread.Start();

        TcpListener Server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(Ev.LocalHost), Ev.WebsocketPort);
        Server.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Websocket Connected...");

            //Thread WebsocketThread = new Thread(WebsocketClientHandler);
            //WebsocketThread.Start(Client);
            WebsocketClientHandler(Client);

        }
    }

    public static void WebsocketClientHandler(object c)
    {
        byte[] Bytes;
        TcpClient Client = (TcpClient)c;
        NetworkStream Stream = Client.GetStream();
        bool connected = true;

        try
        {
            Bytes = new byte[Client.Available];
            Stream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
            string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

                // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                Stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            }

            //Not sure How to send to connected websocket clients.
            while (NewData)
            {
                //Send to webclient...


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            connected = false;
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}

public class UdpReceiver
{
    public bool MessageReceived = false;
    public int Port { get; set; }

    public UdpReceiver() 
    {
        Port = 0;
    }

    public void ReceiveMessages()
    {

        IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        UdpClient u = new UdpClient(e);

        while (true)
        {
            MessageReceived = false;
            byte[] Data = u.Receive(ref e);
            MessageReceived = true;
            //Task.Run(() => ProcessData(Data, c));  //New task to process the data in case another controller is sending data
            ProcessData(Data);
        }
    }

    public void ProcessData(byte[] Data)
    {
        ReceivedData ReceivedData = new ReceivedData();
        ReceivedData.Data = Data;
        ReceivedData.Process();
        //Process() puts the data in a database and is supposed to send to websocket clients.
    }
}
```

Websocket Test Client......

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="WebsocketsExampleWeb.Default" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <style>
    textarea {
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    #output {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    #output > p {
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
    #output span {
      color: blue;
    }
    #output span.error {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <h2>WebSocket</h2>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="6"></textarea>
    <button>send</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
        
        
function connect() {
  var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8077');
  ws.onopen = function() {
     writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
  };

  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    writeToScreen(`<span>RESPONSE: ${e.data}</span>`);
    ws.send("Client Response");
    console.log('Message:', e.data);
  };

  ws.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.', e.reason);
    setTimeout(function() {
      connect();
    }, 1000);
  };

  ws.onerror = function(err) {
    console.error('Socket encountered error: ', err.message, 'Closing socket');
    ws.close();
  };
}
        
function writeToScreen(message) {
  output.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<p>${message}</p>`);
}
        

connect();        
        
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, **do not try to reimplement the WebSocket protocol yourself.** It's extremely complex, and C# already has a perfectly good `WebSocket` implementation already.

- Make everything `async` where possible.
- Use `HttpListener` instead of `TcpListener`, and upgrade each received context to a web socket.
- Put each context in a list so you can continue listening. Make sure to lock the list when you use it.

```cs
class MainClass
{
    private static readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private static readonly List<HttpListenerWebSocketContext> _sockets = new();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Receiver v1.0.0");
        ExternalVariables Ev = new ExternalVariables();
        Ev.Get();

        UdpReceiver r = new UdpReceiver(_sockets, cts.Token);
        r.Port = Ev.ReceivingPort;
        
        var Server = new HttpListener();
        Server.Prefixes.Add("http://+:" + Ev.WebsocketPort);
        Server.Start();

        Task.Run(r.ReceiveMessages);

        // need a way of shutting everything down
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            eventArgs.Cancel = true;
        };
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var context = await Server.GetContextAsync(cts.Token);
                Console.WriteLine("Websocket Connected...");
                // hand off the client to another task so we can continue listening
                Task.Run(() => WebsocketClientHandler(context));
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {}
    }

    public static async Task WebsocketClientHandler(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var socket = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);

            lock (_sockets)
            {
                _sockets.Add(socket);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            context.Response.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class UdpReceiver
{
    public int Port { get; set; }
    private List<HttpListenerWebSocketContext> _contexts;
    private CancellationToken _token;

    public UdpReceiver(List<HttpListenerWebSocketContext> contexts, CancellationToken token) 
    {
        Port = 0;
        _contexts = contexts;
        _token = token;
    }

    public async Task ReceiveMessages()
    {
        IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        using var u = new UdpClient(e);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var response = await u.ReceiveAsync(_token);
                ProcessData(response.Buffer);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {}
    }

    public void ProcessData(byte[] Data)
    {
        ReceivedData ReceivedData = new ReceivedData();
        ReceivedData.Data = Data;
        ReceivedData.Process();
        // broadcast to all sockets
        List<HttpListenerWebSocketContext> list;
        lock (_contexts)
        {
            list = _contexts.ToList();
        }
        foreach (var context in list)
        {
            await SendToSocket(context, Data)
        }
    }

    public static async Task SendToSocket(HttpListenerContext context, byte[] bytes)
    {
        try
        {
            await context.WebSocket.SendAsync(bytes, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, _token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            connected = false;
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            lock(_sockets)
            {
                _contexts.Remove(context);  // remove failed context
                context.WebSocket.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to run the code on my machine.  The problem I'm having is the WebSocket Handshake process between the web browser and my code. It shows the client connecting but I get an exception in WebsocketClientHandler - AcceptWebSocketAsync.  The exception is The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: You might need a subprotocol there `AcceptWebSocketAsync("someProtocolNameHere")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working prototype.  I was able to connect/disconnect multiple web clients to receive the messages.  It also handles multiple UDP clients.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public static readonly List<WebsocketConnection> _clientstreams = new List<WebsocketConnection>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Receiver v1.0.0");
        ExternalVariables Ev = new ExternalVariables();
        Ev.Get();

        UdpReceiver r = new UdpReceiver(_clientstreams, cts.Token);
        r.Port = Ev.ReceivingPort;

        TcpListener Server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(Ev.LocalHost), Ev.WebsocketPort);
        Server.Start();

        Task.Run(r.ReceiveMessages);

        while (true)
        {
            WebsocketConnection Client = new WebsocketConnection();
            Client.Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient();
            bool NewClient = Client.GetConnection();

            if (NewClient)
            {

                lock (_clientstreams)
                {
                    _clientstreams.Add(Client);
                    Console.WriteLine("Added Websocket client to the list");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class UdpReceiver
{
    public int Port { get; set; }
    private List<WebsocketConnection> _clientstreams;
    private  static CancellationToken _token;

    public UdpReceiver(List<WebsocketConnection> ClientStreams, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Port = 0;
        _clientstreams = ClientStreams;
        _token = token;
    }

    public async Task ReceiveMessages()
    {
        IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        var u = new UdpClient(e);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var response = await u.ReceiveAsync();
                ProcessDataAsync(response.Buffer);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) 
        { 
        
        }
    }

    public async Task ProcessDataAsync(byte[] Data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received Data");
        ReceivedData ReceivedData = new ReceivedData();
        ReceivedData.Data = Data;
        ReceivedData.Process();

        // broadcast to all sockets
        List<WebsocketConnection> list;
        lock (_clientstreams)
        {
            list = _clientstreams.ToList();
        }
        foreach (WebsocketConnection c in list)
        {

            await SendToSocket(c, ReceivedData);
        }

    }

    public async Task SendToSocket(WebsocketConnection Stream, ReceivedData Data)
    {
        try
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data.SwipeRecord);
            Stream.SendMessage(json);
            string BrowserMessage = Stream.ReadMessage();

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data.ControllerStatus);
            Stream.SendMessage(json);
            BrowserMessage = Stream.ReadMessage();

            Console.WriteLine(BrowserMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent to Websocket");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Closing WebSocket");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            lock (_clientstreams)
            {
                _clientstreams.Remove(Stream);  // remove failed context
                Console.WriteLine("Removed Socket");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class WebsocketConnection
{
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public TcpListener Server { get; set; }
    public TcpClient Client { get; set; }
    public NetworkStream Stream { get; set; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    public int ConnectionTries { get; set; }

    public WebsocketConnection()
    {
        ConnectionTries = 0;
        Client = new TcpClient();
    }

    public bool GetConnection()
    {

        bool NewClient = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Websocket Connection Established...");
        Stream = Client.GetStream();

        ConnectionTries = 0;

        while (!Stream.DataAvailable) ;
        while (Client.Available < 3) ;

        Bytes = new byte[Client.Available];
        Stream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
        string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes);

        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

            // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
            // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
            // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
            // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
            string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
            string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
            byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
            string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

            // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
            byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

            Stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            NewClient = true;

        }
        return NewClient;
    }

    public void Handshake(string s)
    {

        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            Bytes = new byte[Client.Available];
            Stream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
            s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

                // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                Stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(string Msg)
    {

        byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Msg);
        byte lengthHeader = 0;
        byte[] lengthCount = new byte[] { };

        if (sendBytes.Length <= 125)
            lengthHeader = (byte)sendBytes.Length;

        if (125 < sendBytes.Length && sendBytes.Length < 65535) //System.UInt16
        {
            lengthHeader = 126;

            lengthCount = new byte[] {
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 8),
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length)
                        };
        }

        if (sendBytes.Length > 65535)//max 2_147_483_647 but .Length -> System.Int32
        {
            lengthHeader = 127;
            lengthCount = new byte[] {
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 56),
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 48),
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 40),
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 32),
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 24),
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 16),
                    (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 8),
                    (byte)sendBytes.Length,
                };
        }

        List<byte> responseArray = new List<byte>() { 0b10000001 };

        responseArray.Add(lengthHeader);
        responseArray.AddRange(lengthCount);
        responseArray.AddRange(sendBytes);

        Stream.Write(responseArray.ToArray(), 0, responseArray.Count);
    }

    public string ReadMessage()
    {
        string Message = "";
        Stream.ReadTimeout = 50;

        Stream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);

        string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes);

        bool fin = (Bytes[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
            mask = (Bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"
        int opcode = Bytes[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
            offset = 2;
        ulong msglen = Bytes[1] & (ulong)0b01111111;

        if (msglen == 126)
        {
            // bytes are reversed because websocket will print them in Big-Endian, whereas
            // BitConverter will want them arranged in little-endian on windows
            msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { Bytes[3], Bytes[2] }, 0);
            offset = 4;
        }
        else if (msglen == 127)
        {
            // To test the below code, we need to manually buffer larger messages — since the NIC's autobuffering
            // may be too latency-friendly for this code to run (that is, we may have only some of the bytes in this
            // websocket frame available through client.Available).
            msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { Bytes[9], Bytes[8], Bytes[7], Bytes[6], Bytes[5], Bytes[4], Bytes[3], Bytes[2] }, 0);
            offset = 10;
        }

        if (msglen == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("msglen == 0");
        }
        else if (mask)
        {
            byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
            byte[] masks = new byte[4] { Bytes[offset], Bytes[offset + 1], Bytes[offset + 2], Bytes[offset + 3] };
            offset += 4;

            for (ulong i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                decoded[i] = (byte)(Bytes[(int)offset + (int)i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
            Console.WriteLine("175 WebsocketConnection {0}", text);
            Message = text;
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("mask bit not set");

        Console.WriteLine();
        return Message;
    }

    public bool IsSocketConnected()
    {
        
        bool part1 = Client.Client.Poll(50, SelectMode.SelectRead);
        bool part2 = (Client.Client.Available == 0);
        if ((part1 && part2 ) || !Client.Client.Connected)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```